# using gdb how to check stack info of program having scanf

Tags: c

How to check stack info for a program in which input in taken using scanf? I have tried to do it..  it is going into printed function and asking to enter the value but it is not taking the input.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what you have tried. Otherwise it's hard to guess what you want.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).